# How to exclude fields from SimpleForm

Tags: admin-on-rest

I know `<SimpleForm>` is using redux-form.
I want to exclude specific fields from being sent when I submit the form.
When I edit my entity "User" the RestClient send a GET_ONE request and my API response this:

```
{
name: "Lior",
age: "100",
type: "Manager",
}
```

The `<SimpleForm>` is like this:

```
<SimpleForm> 
  <TextInput source="name"/>
  <TextInput source="age"/>
</SimpleForm>
```

When I send the form, the fields I see in the request are: name, age and **type** even when there is no "input" or "field" for **type**.

How can I avoid from "type" to be sent?

- The API has to return it, I need it for `<Show>` and more..
- I don't to hard coded my RestClient just to remove the "type" because it is
  not happening just in "User" model but in many other models.
- I don't want to "usset" it on the API controller side.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no react-admin way to doing this. I think a restClient middleware is the way to go, but you don't want that. What you can do is to create a HOC using `mapProps` of recompose and wrap `SimpleForm` with it. Something like (untested code):

```
const withLimitedProps = properties => mapProps(({save,...props}) => ({...props,save: (record,redirect) => save(properties.reduce((acc,property)=>{
  acc[property]=record[property]
},{})});

const UserEditForm = withLimitedProps(['name','age'])(SimpleForm)
```

The save prop is proxied, and the record that's submitted is reduced. You can always add more functionality, like selecting the current fields from the redux-form state and reducing on them only. This would give the behaviour that you want.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer! I'll give it a try

Comment: Hi... I added same question in react-admin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55010068/react-admin-exclude-record-from-the-redux-form

Answer (score 1):

You can customize your `restClient` to only send a subset of fields when calling `UPDATE`:

```
case UPDATE:
    url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`;
    options.method = 'PUT';
    const { name, age } = params.data; // type is ignored
    options.body = JSON.stringify({ name, age });
```

Comment: Thanks Francois, I mentioned this this solution in my post. Unfortunately it is not good for me because I will need to have a custom case in my restClient for each model in my project (around 20).

Comment: You can *decorate* your rest client with another function, which removes the field(s) you don't want from the request payloads. See [Decorating REST Clients](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/RestClients.html#decorating-your-rest-client-example-of-file-upload) in the aor documentation for more details.